# Jquery should return one array of data from form, returns two

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, fieldset

I'm working with a form of radio buttons and arrays using Jquery, but I am having trouble recording the selected values into one array. Here's my code:

```js
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
   //do other stuff with it later 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form>

 <fieldset id="group1">
 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="group1"" value="STEM"> 
  <label for="r1"> STEM (Science, Tech, Engineering and Math)</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="group1"" value="HUMAN"> 
  <label for="r2">Humanities (Art, History, Music, Language) </label>
   
 </div>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset id="group2">
 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="group2" value="EXTRO"> 
  <label for="r3"> Extrovert (Like being around other people)</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="r4" name="group2" value="INTRO"> 
  <label for="r4">Introvert (Don't like being around other people)</label>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

I would like to to output into one array, but currently it outputs into an array for every fieldset, how do I fix this?

Ciao.

Comment: Only returns one array here https://jsfiddle.net/5zxLrcht/ Really not clear what you are asking or trying to do. Show expected results. Also suggest you read the documentation

Comment: @Web_Designer huh? it contains objects at both those index, not arrays. Exactly as documented

Comment: @charlietfl Your right. I was wrong. I misread the console.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I don't understand the question correctly but it seems like the output of the function is an array of objects, [{name: 'group1', value: ...}, {name: 'group2', value: ...}]
So, if you just want the values only in one array, this seems like will do the job.

```
var x = $("form").serializeArray().map((ob) => ob.value);
```

(I wanted to ask details but I can't comment since I don't have enough reputation... hope it helps.)